# Password strength checker

Tags: javascript, security, validation, authentication

I would like to receive feedback about my code.  Is there any better way to shorten the code or is it fine?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4mg/1/)

```
var pass_strength;
function IsEnoughLength(str,length){
    if ((str == null) || isNaN(length))
        return false;
    else if (str.length < length)
        return false;
    return true;
}
function HasMixedCase(passwd){
    if(passwd.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))
        if ( passwd.split(/[a-z]/).length >= 3 && passwd.split(/[A-Z]/).length >= 3)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    else
        return false;
}
function HasNumeral(passwd){
    if(passwd.match(/[0-9]/))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
function HasSpecialChars(passwd){
    if(passwd.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]/))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
function CheckPasswordStrength(pwd)
{
    if (IsEnoughLength(pwd,14) && HasMixedCase(pwd) && HasNumeral(pwd) && HasSpecialChars(pwd))
        pass_strength = "<b><font style='color:olive'>Very strong</font></b>";
    else if (IsEnoughLength(pwd,10) && HasMixedCase(pwd) && HasNumeral(pwd) && HasSpecialChars(pwd))
        pass_strength = "<b><font style='color:Blue'>Strong</font></b>";
    else if (IsEnoughLength(pwd,10) && HasMixedCase(pwd) && HasNumeral(pwd))
        pass_strength = "<b><font style='color:Green'>Medium</font></b>";
    else
        pass_strength = "<b><font style='color:red'>Weak</font></b>";
    document.getElementById('pwd_strength').innerHTML = "Password strength: " + pass_strength;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a password doesn't have to have mixed case, special characters or numbers to be strong - It can be strong with nothing but 4 or 5 english words. See http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Use an existing [realistic password strength estimator like *zxcvbn*](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn).

Answer (score 10):

1. You can replace all of the

   ```
   if(x.match(...))
       return true;
   else
       return false;
   ```

   with:

   ```
   return x.match(...) !== null;
   ```

   or if you're content with returning a truthy/falsy value instead of proper booleans you can even simplify it to:

   ```
   return x.match(...)
   ```
2. `IsEnoughLength` is ungrammatical. I'd use `IsLongEnough`
3. You're mixing the password strength estimation with presentation logic. You should have one function which returns a value indicating the strength of the password and another which manipulates the DOM.
4. Use CSS classes to format the text instead of `<b>` and `<font style=`
5. Personally I wouldn't bother with argument checking in such a simple internal function. But if you do, throw an exception on programmer error, don't just return false.

   ```
   if ((str == null) || isNaN(length))
       return false;
   ```

   should be something like

   ```
   if (str == null)
       throw new Error("str must not be null");
   if(isNaN(length))
       throw new Error("length must be a number");
   ```

   (or a fancier exception class if you want)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try like that :)

Answer (score 5):

As [@CodesInChaos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1482/codesinchaos) has already pointed out, the boolean expressions can be simplified, a lot. For example:

```
function HasMixedCase(passwd) {
    return passwd.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)
        && passwd.split(/[a-z]/).length >= 3
        && passwd.split(/[A-Z]/).length >= 3;
}
function HasNumeral(passwd) {
    return passwd.match(/[0-9]/);
}
function HasSpecialChars(passwd) {
    return passwd.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]/);
}
```

In addition, I would simplify the method that checks the length like this:

```
function IsLongEnough(passwd, length) {
    return passwd && passwd.length > length;
}
```

This will only return true if `passwd` is not undefined and long enough.

And I dropped the validation of the `length` parameter. For one thing, it was unnecessary: `IsLongEnough(word, undefined)` and `IsLongEnough(word, NaN)` will always return false. For another thing, if you are calling password validation methods with invalid parameters, you are in big trouble!